# How to play the sound effect play when page change in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to play the sound effect when I go to next page. Is it possible do in flutter? If can, can I know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to play sound in Flutter, head over [here](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player)

Code: `AssetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer().open(Audio("assets/audios/song1.mp3"),);`